# Creating Private Variables with and without Closures

Tags: javascript, closures, iife

Recently, I have been trying to learn about private variables and closures in JavaScript. I just learned about IIFEs and how they can be used with closures to create "private" variables and functions. Below is an example I understand.

```
let test = (function() {
  
  let name = "";
  
  let getName = function() {
    return name;
  }
  
  let setName = function(newName) {
    name = newName;
  }
  
  return {
    getName: getName,
    setName: setName
  };
  
})();

test.setName("Bob");
test.getName(); // "Bob"
test.name; // undefined
```

However, this leaves me wondering, why couldn't I have just done this with a regular function expression, and then invoked the expression and then just saved that to a variable. This new variable would also have a private name value. For example:

```
let test2 = function() {
  
  let name = "";
  
  let getName = function() {
    return name;
  }
  
  let setName = function(newName) {
    name = newName;
  }
  
  return {
    getName: getName,
    setName: setName
  };
  
}

let test3 = test2();

test3.setName("Bob");
test3.getName(); // "Bob"
test3.name; // undefined
```

Is there some benefit to the IIFE method vs a regular function expression that I just invoke right after I define it?

Thanks!

Comment: Your two cases should work exactly the same. There's nothing magical about IIFE.

Comment: The only difference is that the *calling* of the function is directly inlined, and you can't call the function a second time. It's a one-off, compared to your normal function declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The benefit is that an IIFE is just an expression. No changes are made to the enclosing namespace (well, at least not by the IIFE itself directly). It's useful when you need a scope in order to do some work, but you're in a context that only allows a single expression. The IIFE can be anything, a complete program perhaps, but it returns a single value for the enclosing context (like an object initializer, for example).

Answer (score 1):

The two codes are equivalent, but the second version creates an unnecessary global variable `test2` (assuming this is top-level code).

IIFEs are somewhat like top-level versions of anonymous functions -- you use them when you only need the code in one place, so there's no need to give it a permanent name.

Comment: So `const foo = function() {const bar = function() {}}`, `bar` is globally defined?

Comment: No, but `foo` is globally defined.

Comment: Isn't "may create" more appropriate, since the scope is not referenced and global is an assumption?

Comment: True, I assumed that the question was about top-level code. That's the most common place to use IIFEs.